# i want to know if my code is correct and after i want when user give age<18 the onclick button disappears

Tags: javascript, html

i try to do this: Create a web page using HTML and JavaScript. On the website where your name will appear. · Fill in a table with Student Objects. · These objects have 3 fields (fullname, age, amka). The creation of these objects will be done using Constructor (Note the fullname field is the name and is given as follows: "First name - Last name" · The table that is filled until an object is given under the age of 18. ATTENTION this object does not will be inserted in the table.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <script>
    
    
    
            function createPerson() {
                    var fullname = document.getElementById('inputValueFullname').value;
                    var age = document.getElementById('inputValueAge').value;
                    var amka = document.getElementById('inputValueAmka').value;
    
            function person(fullname, age, amka) {
            this.fullname = fullname;
            this.age = age;
            this.amka = amka;
      }
      var myArray = [];
      var NewPerson = new person(fullname, age, amka);
      if(age && age>= 18 && fullname && amka){
    
        myArray.push(NewPerson)
      } else {
            
    
      }
    
      console.log(NewPerson);
    }
     </script>
    
     
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <label>Fullname: <input type="text" id="inputValueFullname"></label>
        <label>Age:<input type="text" id="inputValueAge"></label>
        <label>Amka:<input type="text" id="inputValueAmka"></label>
        <button type="button" onclick=" createPerson();">Add</button>
    
        <table id="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name/Surname</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>AMKA</th><br><br><br><br><br>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I assume AMKA is an identification number as when i tried searching what is that about and the only result i got was a company or a greek citizen ID. The JavaScript function to print data to table can be done without using any array.

```
    <script>
    function publishToTable() {
        const fullname = document.getElementById('fullname').value;
        const age = document.getElementById('age').value;
        const amka = document.getElementById('amka').value;
        const error = document.getElementById('error');

        if (age && age>= 18 && fullname && amka) {
            const tableElement = document.getElementById('table');
            const trElement = document.createElement('tr');
            const tbodyElement = document.createElement('tbody');
            const fullnameEle = document.createElement('td');
            const ageEle = document.createElement('td');
            const amkaEle = document.createElement('td');
            fullnameEle.innerHTML = fullname;
            ageEle.innerHTML = age;
            amkaEle.innerHTML = amka;
            trElement.appendChild(fullnameEle);
            trElement.appendChild(ageEle);
            trElement.appendChild(amkaEle);
            tbodyElement.appendChild(trElement);
            tableElement.appendChild(tbodyElement);
        }
    }
</script>
```

I think i fixed your issue:
[js_issue_solved.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HS7q4.png)

Full Code:

```html
// <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <script>
        function publishToTable() {
            const fullname = document.getElementById('fullname').value;
            const age = document.getElementById('age').value;
            const amka = document.getElementById('amka').value;
            const error = document.getElementById('error');

            if (age && age>= 18 && fullname && amka) {
                const tableElement = document.getElementById('table');
                const trElement = document.createElement('tr');
                const tbodyElement = document.createElement('tbody');
                const fullnameEle = document.createElement('td');
                const ageEle = document.createElement('td');
                const amkaEle = document.createElement('td');
                fullnameEle.innerHTML = fullname;
                ageEle.innerHTML = age;
                amkaEle.innerHTML = amka;
                trElement.appendChild(fullnameEle);
                trElement.appendChild(ageEle);
                trElement.appendChild(amkaEle);
                tbodyElement.appendChild(trElement);
                tableElement.appendChild(tbodyElement);
            }
        }
    </script>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>


    <div class="complete">
        <div class="form">
            <label>Fullname: <input id="fullname" type="text"></label>
            <label>Age: <input id="age" type="number"></label>
            <label>AMKA: <input id="amka" type="text"></label>
            <span id="error"></span>
            <button onclick="publishToTable()">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div id="tables">
            <table id="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>|Name/Surname|   </th>
                        <th>|Age|   </th>
                        <th>|AMKA|   </th><br><br><br><br><br>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your help you help me a lot...i want one more think how can i do invisible the submit when user give age<18 because i want to stop to take more inputs..thanks again